# Is there a way to prevent envoy from adding specific headers?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

According to the docs here https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#x-forwarded-proto
Envoy proxy adds the Header `X-Forwarded-Proto` to the request, for some reason the header value is wrong; it set it as `http` although the incoming requests scheme is `https` which cause some problems in my application code since it depends on the correct value of this header.

Is this a bug in envoy? Can I prevent envoy from doing this?

Comment: I assume you use istio as you used the istio tag, I checked for this issue on github and there is related [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7964) about that. As far as I understand you can use envoy filter to change all the http X-Forwarded-Proto to https, take a look at [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7964#issuecomment-434466264) and [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7964#issuecomment-554241818) comment. Additionally take a look at  [alpha api](https://preliminary.istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/network-topologies/).

Comment: @Jakub thank you very much that's exactly was my issue, I solved it the same way one of the comments mentioned.

Comment: Happy it works for you! I have add an answer for more visibility. If it helped consider up voting/accepting the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments there is related [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7964) about that.

> Is there a way to prevent envoy from adding specific headers?

There is istio dev @howardjohn [comment](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7964#issuecomment-679397836) about that

> We currently have two options:
>
> - [EnvoyFilter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/)
> - [Alpha api](https://preliminary.istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/network-topologies/)
>
> There will not be a third; instead we will promote the alpha API.

---

So the first option would be envoy filter.

---

There are 2 answers with that in above github issue.

[Answer](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7964#issuecomment-554241818) provided by @jh-sz

> In general, use_remote_address should be set to true when Envoy is deployed as an edge node (aka a front proxy), whereas it may need to be set to false when Envoy is used as an internal service node in a mesh deployment.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: xff-trust-hops
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      context: ANY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager"
          use_remote_address: true
          xff_num_trusted_hops: 1
```

---

**AND**

---

[Answer](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7964#issuecomment-434466264) provided by @vadimi

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: my-app-filter
spec:
  workloadLabels:
    app: my-app
  filters:
  - listenerMatch:
      portNumber: 5120
      listenerType: SIDECAR_INBOUND
    filterName: envoy.lua
    filterType: HTTP
    filterConfig:
      inlineCode: |
        function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
          request_handle:headers():replace("x-forwarded-proto", "https")
        end
        function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
        end
```

---

The second option would be Alpha api, this feature is actively in development and is considered pre-alpha.

---

> Istio provides the ability to manage settings like [X-Forwarded-For](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#x-forwarded-for) (XFF) and [X-Forwarded-Client-Cert](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#x-forwarded-client-cert) (XFCC), which are dependent on how the gateway workloads are deployed. This is currently an in-development feature. For more information on X-Forwarded-For, see the IETF’s [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239).
>
> You might choose to deploy Istio ingress gateways in various network topologies (e.g. behind Cloud Load Balancers, a self-managed Load Balancer or directly expose the Istio ingress gateway to the Internet). As such, these topologies require different ingress gateway configurations for transporting correct client attributes like IP addresses and certificates to the workloads running in the cluster.
>
> Configuration of XFF and XFCC headers is managed via MeshConfig during Istio installation or by adding a pod annotation. Note that the Meshconfig configuration is a global setting for all gateway workloads, while pod annotations override the global setting on a per-workload basis.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is most likely because you have one or more proxies in front of Envoy/Istio.

You need to tell Envoy how many proxies you have in front of it so that it can set forwarded headers correctly (such as `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-For`).

In Istio **1.4+** you can achieve this with an Envoy filter:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: xff-trust-hops
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      context: ANY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager"
          use_remote_address: true
          xff_num_trusted_hops: 1 # Change as needed
```

Note that if you have multiple proxies in front of Envoy you have to change the `xff_num_trusted_hops` variable to the correct amount. For example if you have a GCP or AWS cloud load balancer, you might have to increase this value to 2.

In Istio **1.8+**, you will be able to configure this via the Istio operator instead, example:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  meshConfig:
    defaultConfig:
      gatewayTopology:
        numTrustedProxies: 1 # Change as needed
```

More information is available [here](https://preliminary.istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/network-topologies/).

Comment: Thanks for answering my issue was exactly the same issue described [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7964)